# fuse python script not running in background using php

Tags: php, python, shell, fuse

i am trying to run a file sytem for dropbox ff4d ( from github) in background using php 
the purpose if that user will get his dropbox files mount on the server and then i will give the path to a web based explorer (like eXtplorer) so user can manage his file 
the script is working fine when using command shell 
but when i using the exec function it working printing out the last line of the command shell 
and that it . i can not get the folder mount 
here the code in php :

```
$folder = $_POST['foldername'];

$oldumask = umask(0000);
$path = "/var/www/cloudsite/" . $folder;

if(mkdir($path, 0777, true)) {
    echo $path . " success directory created ";
} else {
    echo $path . "error directory not created ";
}
umask($oldumask);

#$command = '/usr/bin/python /var/www/cloudsite/ff4d/./ff4d.py '. $path .'c7ZYof8Bl0YAAAAAAAAAARThZwAUexbukmv3rMEprPJWFcoQSKGWtWHQBYM40OgC';
$result = exec($command);

if ($result){
    echo " </br> execution success";

}else{
    echo "</br> error not success";
}

echo $result;
```

and here what i get in the browser it seems like it working but just hang here nothing mount in the created directory : 
var/www/cloudsite/chao success directory created
execution successStarting FUSE...

Answer (score 0):

Within the latest release of my ff4d.py script I've added a "background" switch (-bg).

https://github.com/realriot/ff4d

BTW: **Please remove your access key (and revoke it afterwards) because it holds your personal information and ALL your data...**